# How to get all the folder name from internal storage and show it in the text-field?

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

What I want to do is to view all the folder name in the text-field from a specific location. For example, the given data path is-

```
android/data/
```

Here, inside data path we have some folders like `com.facebook.katana`, `com.android.browser`, `com.android.calendar` etc. Now what I want to do is to show all the folder names in a the text-field. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the os.path module from python:

```
import os

path = 'android/data/com.something'

os.path.split(path)[-1]
```

returns the last element of your path structure:

```
'com.something'
```

**EDIT:**
If you need multiple parts of your data path, split it at `/`.

This returns a list of all path elements. If you want to find multiple elements with a shared pattern, you can use Regex to find those. In your example case:

```
import re

path = 'android/data/com.something/com.facebook/com.skype'

split_path = path.split('/')

elements = [element for element in split_path if re.match(\A['com.'], element)]
```

Output:

```
['com.something', 'com.facebook', 'com.skype']
```

The `re.match` here takes every element that starts with `com.`. Of course you can modify your regex according to your needs.

Comment: If there multiple folder name on the data path which I want to view?

Comment: you would do: npath = os.path.split('/'). Then: n = len(npath) which will give you the number of path elements. And subsequently : npath[0], npath[1], npath[2] till npath[n] will give you the individual path elements.

Comment: I am not sure yet about getting folder names.

Comment: could you give a more specific example of what you want to do exactly?

Comment: Here, inside data path we have some folders like `com.facebook.katana`, `com.facebook.browser`, `com.facebook.calendar` etc. Now what I want to do is to show all the folder names in a the text-field.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
import os
p = "android/data/com.something"
file = os.path.basename(p)
```

file contains now: 'com.something'
then you assign file to your text-field variable. For example:

in your python code:

```
self.my-text-field.text = file
```

and in your kv file:

```
my-text-field:my-text-field
TextInput:
    id: my-text-field
```

Comment: Suppose there are more folders like com.example( e.g. com.skype ) and I want to view them all, what is the procedure?

Comment: see my comment above under the answer of Jones1220: you would do: npath = os.path.split('/'). Then: n = len(npath) which will give you the number of path elements. And subsequently : npath[0], npath[1], npath[2] till npath[n] will give you the individual path elements.

Comment: Here, inside data path we have some folders like `com.facebook.katana`, `com.facebook.browser`, `com.facebook.calendar` etc. Now what I want to do is to show all the folder names in a the text-field.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this,
if you are using a relative path you need use the second line. otherwise skip it
`File file = new File(filename);
 file = new File(file.getAbsolutePath());
 String directory = file.getParent();
 File dirAsFile = file.getParentFile();`